# Update SQLAlchemy field threadsafe from multiple processes

Tags: multithreading, sqlalchemy, distributed

I have a database table that describes a job that is processing on a distributed system.  So the entire job is split up into many tiny parts and each part is processed on a different machine in it's own environment.

I want to keep a simple log of how each process fared, so each node is connecting to the same job table with SQLAlchemy and appending their job number and status to the end of a UnicodeText field.

I expect to see something like:

```
Part 1: complete<br/>
Part 2: complete<br/>
Part 3: error<br/>
Part 4: complete<br/>
...etc
```

I'm simply doing a `process.log += "Part 1: complete\n"` on each node when it finishes processing the part.  Then a `session.commit()`

I'm aware that the part numbers will be out of order and that is fine for my purposes, but what is happening instead is that I am only getting a few entries of the total parts.  I assume that it is because many jobs are finishing at the same time and doing the append += is not thread safe.

I'm not great with the session, so I don't know all of the tricks to get it configured.  I did try using a NullPool to no avail.

Is there any way to make the append operation thread safe in a distributed environment like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update an - I assume - text field *in parallel* this is how it's going on internally: each instance reads the original field when instantiating the object (`sessionmaker` takes care of this, so that for each thread there's is an instance of the data-holding entity) and appends its part on *its* version of the field. Then its own instance is comitted. What you get as a result is a - perfectly thread-safe - last version. 
The last object written wins.

If you want *all* your data committed to the same field with *this* data structure, you'd have to throw away any benefit of threading, and synchronize your reading and writing of the entity instances, so that each thread waits with reading the data (for append) until after its predecessor comitted.

What you *should* do: change you data structure to *use* the benefits of an SQL database, and make *each* update its own SQL record.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification. I kind of knew something like that was going on, but couldn't nail down the exact order of operations.  In this case, having a record for each part was overkill for what I needed, but in general I think you are right about using the database to your advantage.  I worked around it somehow, but it's been so long that I don't remember how.  :O